# Removing KDE from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kde

I was trying to install the [KDE desktop](https://www.kde.org) and I did `sudo apt-get install kubuntu*` which I think installed more than I wanted. What is the best way to get rid of all of this and then just install the desktop?

If I do `sudo apt-get remove kubuntu*` will it get rid of it all?

The specific reason I am asking this is because when I booted into KDE after the `kubuntu*` installation, I saw things I had never seen before. The lock screen has a slide to unlock and a slide to sleep feature (I don’t want that) and the apps have super large buttons.

I’m wondering if maybe I installed some kind of mobile Kubuntu interface by accident? What is it that I am installing with `kubuntu*` that I might not be installing by `kubuntu-desktop` which would make my desktop do these weird things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer on “Ask Ubuntu”](https://askubuntu.com/a/74021) this command should work:

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt apport-kde apturl-kde ark bluedevil cdparanoia cdrdao docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer dvd+rw-tools freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm growisofs gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk kde-config-touchpad kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdebase-runtime kdegames-card-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-groupware kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepim-wizards kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdm kdoctools kfind khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kpat kppp ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-kde libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libarchive1 libassuan0 libattica0 libaudio2 libbluedevil1 libboost-program-options1.46.1 libcalendarsupport4 libcanberra-pulse libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libdbusmenu-qt2 libdebconf-kde0 libdiscid0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libepub0 libeventviews4 libflac++6 libgadu3 libgif4 libgpgme++2 libgpgme11 libgpod4-nogtk libgps19 libgrantlee-core0 libhyphen0 libibus-qt1 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libiodbc2 libk3b6 libkabc4 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdegames5a libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi2 libkworkspace4 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm0 libmailcommon4 libmailtransport4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmhash2 libmicroblog4 libmpcdec6 libmsn0.3 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmuonprivate1 libmusicbrainz3-6 libmysqlclient16 libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi2 libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libpth20 libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqrencode3 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtgui4 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit4 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-impress libreoffice-kde libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-writer libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libssh-4 libstlport4.6ldbl libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi2 libtemplateparser4 libtextcat-data libtextcat0 libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 libweather-ion6 libxml2-utils libyajl1 libzip1 muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.1 ntrack-module-libnl-0 obexd-client odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-kimpanel-backend-ibus plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text printer-applet pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip python-uno qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer qdbus quassel quassel-data rekonq shared-desktop-ontologies software-properties-kde soprano-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings uno-libs3 update-manager-kde ure usb-creator-kde userconfig virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common wodim xfonts-mathml
```

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers made no effect on removing that KDE-trash. But I've completely fixed it in another way:

1. Find all locations of the app (move to the root dir. first):
   `find kdeconnect*;`
2. Sequentially remove all folders from the list you get as a result of previous command with all data stored inside them:
   `sudo rm -rf <dir_name>`

Answer (score -1):

You should try with this command [which you can read more about from this tutorial](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu):

```
 sudo apt-get remove akonadi-facebook akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark audiocd-kio bluedevil calligra-data calligra-libs colord-kde cryptsetup dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kamoso kate kcalc kde-base-artwork kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-tablet kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-config-touchpad kde-style-oxygen kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-approver kde-telepathy-auth-handler kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-data kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler kde-telepathy-integration-module kde-telepathy-minimal kde-telepathy-send-file kde-telepathy-text-ui kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegames-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-strigi-plugins kdesudo kexi khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact korganizer kpat kppp krdc krita krita-data ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager libassuan0 libaudiocdplugins4 libbluedevil1 libcalendarsupport4 libchm1 libcln6 libdebconf-kde0 libepub0 libeventviews4 libfftw3-3 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libgtlcore0.8 libgtlfragment0.8 libibus-qt1 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libkateinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw21 libkdecorations4abi1 libkdegames6 libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdgantt2 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-11 libkexiv2-data libkipi-data libkipi9 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkpgp4 libkrossui4 libksane-data libksane0 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent4 libktpchat0 libktpcommoninternalsprivate3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglutils1abi1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi2 liblastfm1 liblightdm-qt-2-0 libllvm3.0 libloudmouth1-0 libmailcommon4 libmailimporter4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmuonprivate1 libmygpo-qt1 libokularcore1abi1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenconnect2 libopenctl0.8 libopenjpeg2 libopenshiva0.8 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpoppler-qt4-4 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqalculate5-data libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqoauth1 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtgstreamerui-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtshiva0.1 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libruby1.9.1 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libspnav0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtemplateparser4 libweather-ion6 libyaml-0-2 libzip2 lightdm-kde-greeter muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme partitionmanager pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widget-telepathy-chat plasma-widget-telepathy-presence plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text print-manager python-pyudev python3-pykde4 python3-pyqt4 python3-sip qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rdesktop rekonq ruby ruby1.9.1 skanlite software-properties-kde systemsettings tasks-icons ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt usb-creator-kde userconfig && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Laurbert515 sorry, I forgot to provide a link. @JakeGould there you got it ;) Regards :)